# Class does not have a suitable operator->

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dictionary, operator-overloading

I'm trying to implement a lock-free map, and I encountered a problem.

In my iterator class I implemented an `operator->` to freely get `first` and `second`:

```
_t_iterator_return<_Kty, _Ty> operator->()
{
    _t_iterator_return<_Kty, _Ty> tmp((int&)Cur->getKey(), Cur->getValue());
    return tmp;
}
```

Which is:

```
template <class _Kty, class _Ty>
struct _t_iterator_return
{
    _Kty& first; // key
    _Ty& second; // val

    _t_iterator_return(_Kty& k, _Ty& v) : first(k), second(v) {}
};
```

Seems norm isn't it? But in my `main()` this:

```
for(LFMap<int, stringc>::iterator it = m.begin(); !it.end(); ++it)
    fprintf(mres, "K: %7d     V: %s\n", it->first, it->second.c_str());
```

Causes a compile-time error: `error C2819: type 'lightforce::core::LFMap<_Kty,_Ty>::_t_iterator_return<_Kty,_Ty>' does not have an overloaded member 'operator ->'`

Nevertheless, this code:

```
for(LFMap<int, stringc>::iterator it = m.begin(); !it.end(); ++it)
        fprintf(mres, "K: %7d     V: %s\n", it.operator->().first, it.operator->().second.c_str());
```

Has been successfully compiled and worked just fine! Why `->` is not working, but `operator->` does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++11 §13.5.6 [over.ref] para 1 states:

> ... An expression `x->m` is interpreted as `(x.operator->())->m` for a class object `x` of type `T` if `T::operator->()` exists and if the operator is selected as the best match function by the overload resolution mechanism (13.3).

Since the type you return from your `operator->` - `_t_iterator_return<_Kty, _Ty>` - doesn't have an `operator ->` it cannot be dereferenced.

Add an `operator ->` to `_t_iterator_return` that simply returns `this`:

```
_t_iterator_return* operator->()
{
    return this;
}
```

Comment: I've added it and got this: `error C2818: application of overloaded 'operator ->' is recursive through type 'lightforce::core::LFMap<_Kty,_Ty>::_t_iterator_return<_Kty,_Ty>'`

Comment: @RomanChehowsky Seems to work correctly in [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eebb74b503f2b09b) and [g++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/317a4c9464745e36). Maybe a MSVS bug.

Comment: no wait, it worked! but `_t_iterator_return<_Kty, _Ty>* operator->{ return this;}`, not `_t_iterator_return<_Kty, _Ty>& operator->{ return *this;}` which i've tried :) Thx a lot!

Comment: @RomanChehowsky Oh good, I'll stop trying to search MSDN for `operator->` bugs ;)